# React redux change item in a list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a table with 50 rows, each row is an item from a list.

I want to set the item as selected when I click on a checkbox in the row.

By doing it, I see that all the 50 rows are rerender.

How can I set only the specific item? (Without shouldcomponentupdate).

```
case ITEM_SELECTED:
        const items = fromJS(state.items)
            items.update(
            items.findIndex(function(item) {
                return item._id == action.id;
            }), function(item) {
                return item.selected = action.selected;
            }
        );
        return {
            ...state,
            items: items.toJS()
        }
```

Thanks :)

Comment: A. No attempted code provide.
B. Very open ended.
C. Sad Panda.

Comment: can share some code also, table as well as the function in which doing the selection :)

Comment: By connecting individual row components rather than a containing component you should be able to avoid the re-render, although I wouldn't bother doing that under most circumstances. As other users mentioned, some more detail would help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add `key` to each item ? React uses `key` to determine if a sibling has changed.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: you have sufficient reputation to comment on any ques, so instead of asking ques as an answer, ask it in comments, post the answer when it actually answer the OP's ques :)